# SQL Having sum(*) = sum(*)

Tags: sql, having

I have a quick question about using a having clause.

I have two tables. 1 with invoices and 1 with payments. This is the select statement I want to use to give me not fully paid invoices:

```
select * 
from invoices i 
where not exists (select * 
                  from payments p 
                  having sum(p.amount) = sum(i.amount))
```

This is not working. Does someone know a solution?

Comment: *This is not working* tells us nothing about your actual problem.

Comment: Can you expand on "this is not working" ? Check out the `Help others reproduce the problem` section on https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Please provide some more context behind the 2 tables (schema, example data, etc.). At a glance, it's not clear the relationship between `invoices` and `payments`, so when you say `SELECT invoices WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT payments)` it's not clear how those 2 tables are related. I don't think you can use `sum(i.amount)` in the subquery though because `i` isn't defined there.

Comment: my understanding, based on the table names, this will not work. you should be doing a left join on a specific  key that is available as per db design

Comment: you need to specify join condition between payments and invoices, what are they joined on?

Comment: Also, to use HAVING clause, you need to have aggregate functions like GROUP BY etc, otherwise you are fine with using WHERE clause to specify your conditions

Answer (score 0):

let's assume the invoices and payments table are joined on invoiceid,
in that case you can join them and specify the condition for join

select i.invoiceid, i.amount,....(other information you want from invoices/payments)
from invoices i , payments p
where i.invoiceid = p.invoiceid
and p.amount <> i.amount

Answer (score 0):

You are thinking somewhat along the right lines, but you need to consider these questions:

1. Sum of payment amount by what?
2. Sum of invoice amount by what?
3. How are the invoice and payment tables related to each other?

Assuming that:

- You have an invoice_id (or similar) in both tables
- Each invoice_id in the invoices table can include multiple line items
- Each invoice_id in the payments table can include multiple line items

Then, if you want to return all rows from the invoices table:

```
SELECT x.*,--get the invoice and all invoice line items
       y.invoice_amount AS total_invoice_payments_received --the current amount received
FROM (SELECT *,
             SUM(amount) OVER (PARTITION BY invoice_id) AS invoice_amount
      FROM invoices) x
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT invoice_id,
                    SUM(amount) AS invoice_amount
             FROM payments
             GROUP BY invoice_id) y ON x.invoice_id = y.invoice_id
WHERE x.invoice_amount <> COALESCE(y.invoice_amount,0); --in case there are no payment records
```

If there's only one line per invoice in the invoices table, then it's simpler:

```
SELECT x.*,--get the invoice and all invoice line items
       y.invoice_amount AS total_invoice_payments_received --the amount in payments
FROM invoices x
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT invoice_id,
                    SUM(amount) AS invoice_amount
             FROM payments
             GROUP BY invoice_id) y ON x.invoice_id = y.invoice_id
WHERE x.invoice_amount <> COALESCE(y.invoice_amount,0); --in case there are no payment records
```